# How can I restore Non-Consumable IAP services from HMS IAP server side?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services

I am implementing HMS plugins to show ads and IAP service for my app through Unity. Everything is fine, ads and IAP are both working fine.

There is one thing that I cannot figure out and that is when I purchase a non-consumable IAP product, the app works fine but when the next time I want to restore that IAP purchase, nothing came back from the server. How can I get all of my IAP data that a user make from that app? And how should I handle non-consumable IAP from my side? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore non-consumable after payment completed, HMS Core (APK) returns a purchase order details JSON string InAppPurchaseData and a signature string inAppDataSignature.

The app can verify the signature string to ensure the accuracy of the order details. If the app has high-security requirements and needs to verify order information on the Huawei IAP server, the app can parse the purchase token parameter from InAppPurchaseData and call below API to send a verification request to Huawei IAP server. The purchase token parameter is used to uniquely identify the mapping between a product and a user.

Server-side [API](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-common-statement-0000001050986127-V5)

```
    POST /applications/purchases/tokens/verify Content-Type: application/json; 
charset=UTF-8 Authorization: 
BasicQVQ6Q1YzQ1NPbVlBaGwrZUtRWExtMTBVV2pyWXZHTVF4MmYvcVMya1B0ZElLY3UwaFJrdFNTMmxwdk1FQkIyY
ldXWGt0REVaR3I4UjFUTTRLMVlmNXdwWU80RG04THdXQWxjaFhEYjBMUjBNTUJtWnFYcGFtazc3THN3UnFJbkhHK28
xekdqRzNSMg== Accept: application/json Content-Length: 143 {   "purchaseToken": 
"00000173741056a37eef310dff9c6a86fec57efafe318ae478e52d9c4261994d64c8f6fc8ea1abbdx5347.5.3
089",   "productId": "prd1" }
```

API-ObtainOwnedPurchases:

Queries information about all purchased in-app products, including consumables, non-consumables, and auto-renewable subscriptions.

● When an app launches, the obtainOwnedPurchases API is called to check whether the delivery failure occurs. If so, redeliver the corresponding products. After the successful redelivery, the consumeOwnedPurchase API is called to consume them.

● If an exception occurs during payment, the obtainOwnedPurchases API is called to check whether the payment is successful. If the delivery failure occurs, redeliver the corresponding product.

● If a product has been purchased but is not consumed, error code 60051 is returned during the payment. In this case, the obtainOwnedPurchases API is called to check whether the delivery failure occurs. If so, redeliver the corresponding product.